# How to integrate firestore-stripe-payments with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

I am using Firebase and have the extension installed and active (https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stripe-firestore-stripe-payments)

How do I actually implement a Stripe Checkout in ReactJS? I am using a subscription product - which has two options - monthly and annually.

I want users to be able to select a subscription type and then pay for it with their credit card - but can see no documentation on how to actually embed this?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the Extension's [POSTINSTALL.md](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/master/firestore-stripe-payments/POSTINSTALL.md#using-the-extension), especially the part "Using the extension". Basically you use this Firebase extension as a backend to [Stripe Checkout flow](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout).